# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client please solove this

Tags: node.js, express

Sir i'm facing this issue in nodejs, expressjs while registring  a user in database.
we here making a pizza ordring app .

**here is issue:**

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\expressJsBySujeet\Realtime-pizza\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (D:\expressJsBySujeet\Realtime-pizza\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:915:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (D:\expressJsBySujeet\Realtime-pizza\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:953:18)
    at D:\expressJsBySujeet\Realtime-pizza\app\http\controllers\authController.js:40:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

here is my code authController.js:

```js
async newUserregister(req, res) {
  const { Uname, email, password } = req.body; // getting data as array distructing
  if (
    !req.body.Uname.trim().length == 0 &&
    !req.body.email.trim().length == 0 &&
    !req.body.password.trim().length == 0
  ) {
    // check email exist or not
    newUser.exists({ email: email }, (err, result) => {
      if (result) {
        req.flash("error", "This Email Already exists");
        req.flash("Uname", Uname);
        req.flash("email", email);
        return res.redirect("/register");
      }
    });
    // create new user in data base
    const encPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const user = new newUser({
      Uname: Uname,
      email: email,
      password: encPass,
    });
    user
      .save()
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        return res.redirect("/ac");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        req.flash("error", "something went wrong");
        return res.redirect("/register");
      });
  } else {
    req.flash("error", "All fields are required");
    req.flash("Uname", Uname);
    req.flash("email", email);

    return res.redirect("/register");
  }
}
```

line no 40 is start with :

> ```js
> req.flash('error','something went wrong')
> return res.redirect('/register')
> ```

i'm creating a user register system in expressjs
**please answer how this will fixed**

Comment: Your `return` statements within async callbacks (eg the one in `newUser.exists()`) are not halting the main thread / synchronous execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until you've finished checking if the user exists or not before creating a new user - otherwise, if you do  `res.redirect('/register')` and then do the same thing later, you'll have redirected twice. Only redirect exactly once.

You should also check if the `.exists` call throws an error, instead of ignoring it.

```
async newUserregister(req, res){
    const { Uname, email, password } = req.body;
    if (!Uname.trim().length || !email.trim().length || !password.trim.length) {
        req.flash('error', 'All fields are required')
        req.flash('Uname', Uname)
        req.flash('email', email)
        return res.redirect('/register')
    }
    newUser.exists({ email }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', 'something went wrong')
            return res.redirect('/register')
        }
        if (result) {
            req.flash('error', 'This Email Already exists')
            req.flash('Uname', Uname)
            req.flash('email', email)
            return res.redirect('/register')
        }
        bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
            .then((encPass) => {
                const user = new newUser({
                    Uname,
                    email,
                    password: encPass
                })
                return user.save();
            })
            .then((user) => {
                console.log(user)
                res.redirect('/ac')
            })
            .catch(err => {
                req.flash('error', 'something went wrong')
                res.redirect('/register')
            });
    });
}
```

The syntax gets a lot easier if `.exists` returns a Promise, or you can change to a Promise-based version of it - then you can catch only at the end, and `await` all the Promises. Something like:

```
async newUserregister(req, res){
    const { Uname, email, password } = req.body;
    if (!Uname.trim().length || !email.trim().length || !password.trim.length) {
        req.flash('error', 'All fields are required')
        req.flash('Uname', Uname)
        req.flash('email', email)
        return res.redirect('/register')
    }
    try {
        const userAlreadyExists = await newUser.exists({ email });
        if (userAlreadyExists) {
            req.flash('error', 'This Email Already exists')
            req.flash('Uname', Uname)
            req.flash('email', email)
            return res.redirect('/register')
        }
        const encPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
        const user = new newUser({
            Uname,
            email,
            password: encPass
        })
        await user.save();
        console.log(user)
        res.redirect('/ac')
    } catch (err) {
        req.flash('error', 'something went wrong')
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
}
```